# How to pass and get an Intent between Activities

Tags: android

I am making a program in which i **need to pass a value from one activity to another** using an *Intent between activities*.

So here is my question *How to Pass and Get an Intent into another activity*.

See my below code, **using button click** i want to pass an intent to another activity..

*FirstActivity.java:*

```
 public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
// Initializing variables
EditText inputName;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen1);

    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    Button btnNextScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNextScreen);

    //Listening to button event
    btnNextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Code to start a new Intent and to pass value


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: tones of links exist on this topic ! it needs just a search!

Comment: made no effort before posting the question !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing hard here, you just need to pass value of name from FirstActivity to SecondActivity by using below code:

```
    btnNextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Starting a new Intent
            Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);

            //Sending data to another Activity
            nextScreen.putExtra("name", inputName.getText().toString());
            startActivity(nextScreen);

        }
    });
}
```

and in second activity use below code in onCreate() method:

```
 TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);     
 Intent i = getIntent();
    // Receiving the Data

    String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
    txtName.setText(name);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context. getApplicationContext() is not recommended

Answer (score 1):

yes **Ketlyen** i agree with *@klamitsuri*

You just **need to pass value** like he shown in code:

```
  Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);

        //Sending data to another Activity
        nextScreen.putExtra("name", inputName.getText().toString());
        startActivity(nextScreen);
```

and to get simply use:

```
  Intent i = getIntent();
// Receiving the Data

String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your firstActivity

```
 btnNextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
       Intent i= new Intent(firstActivity.this,secondActivity.class);
       i.putExtra("key","mystring");// key and the value
       startActivity(i);

    }
  });
}
```

In your second activity onCreate()

```
setContentView(R.layout.second); 
Bundle extras= getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras!=null)
{
 TextView tv= (TextView)findviewById(R.id.textView1);
 String value = extras.getString("key"); // get the value based on the key
 tv.setText(value); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current Activity, create a new Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context. getApplicationContext() not recommended

Comment: @Raghunandan ok. sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the values or data by using startActivityForResult(intent,result);

and to get the values sent by the previous activity override the function onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data);

for Example:

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
 ...

 static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0;

 protected boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
         // When the user center presses, let them pick a contact.
         startActivityForResult(
             new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
             new Uri("content://contacts")),
             PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
        return true;
     }
     return false;
 }

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
         Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             // A contact was picked.  Here we will just display it
             // to the user.
             startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, data));
         }
     }
 }}
```